# Typesetting a cut-off checkerboard for the "Return from the Klondike" problem by S Lloyd

Tags: tables, vertical

I am trying to create a table in LaTeX that looks like this:
[image]

from the problem [Return from the Klondike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_from_the_Klondike)
The best I have managed is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{*{21}{c}}
%\begin{tabular}{*{21}{c@{\hspace{1.25\tabcolsep}}}}
\cline{10-12}   & & & & & & & & &4&7&7& & & & & & & & &  \\
\cline{7-15}    & & & & & &5&4&4&8&3&3&4&6&3& & & & & &  \\
\cline{5-17}    & & & &1&4&5&1&1&1&4&5&1&7&1&3&5& & & &  \\
\cline{4-18}    & & &4&9&4&9&6&7&5&5&5&8&7&6&6&8&5& & &  \\
\cline{3-19}    & &3&7&2&9&8&3&5&6&7&3&9&1&8&7&5&8&5& &  \\
\cline{3-19}    & &1&4&7&8&4&2&9&2&7&1&1&8&2&2&7&6&3& &  \\
\cline{2-20}    &7&2&1&8&5&5&3&1&1&3&1&3&3&4&2&8&6&1&3&  \\
\cline{2-20}    &4&2&6&7&2&5&2&4&2&2&5&4&3&2&8&1&7&7&3&  \\
\cline{2-20}    &4&1&6&5&1&1&1&9&1&4&3&4&4&3&1&9&8&2&7&  \\
\cline{1-21}   4&3&5&2&3&2&2&3&2&4&2&5&3&5&1&1&3&5&5&3&7 \\
\cline{1-21}   2&7&1&5&1&1&3&1&5&3&3&2&4&2&3&7&7&5&4&2&7 \\
\cline{1-21}   2&5&2&2&6&1&2&4&4&6&3&4&1&2&1&2&6&5&1&8&8 \\
\cline{1-21}    &4&3&7&5&1&9&3&4&4&5&2&9&4&1&9&5&7&4&8&  \\
\cline{2-20}    &4&1&6&7&8&3&4&3&4&1&3&1&2&3&2&3&6&2&4&  \\
\cline{2-20}    &7&3&2&6&1&5&3&9&2&3&2&1&5&7&5&8&9&5&4&  \\
\cline{2-20}    & &1&6&7&3&4&8&1&1&1&2&1&2&2&8&9&4&1& &  \\
\cline{3-19}    & &2&5&4&7&8&7&5&6&1&3&5&7&8&7&2&9&3& &  \\
\cline{3-19}    & & &6&5&6&4&6&7&2&5&2&2&6&3&4&7&4& & &  \\
\cline{4-18}    & & & &2&3&1&2&3&3&3&2&1&3&2&1&1& & & &  \\
\cline{5-17}    & & & & & &7&4&4&5&7&3&4&4&7& & & & & &  \\
\cline{7-15}    & & & & & & & & &3&3&4& & & & & & & & &  \\
\cline{10-12}   & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &   
\end{tabular}                       
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which is so ugly I won't post it: the horizontal spacing is all wrong (and I can't seem to fix it using `1.25\tabcolsep`); there are no vertical lines; and the checkerboard background is missing.

Ideally, I'd also be able to add arrows from a specific coordinate to a different one to indicate the solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cut-off check board can be simple drawn by use of `matrix` library of `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,
         nodes={draw, minimum size=1.5em, 
                fill=teal!50, text=white, font=\large,
                inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt, 
                anchor=center},
         every even  column/.style={every odd row/.append style={nodes={fill=black, text=white}}},
         every odd  column/.style={every even row/.append style={nodes={fill=black, text=white}}},
         column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
         row sep=-\pgflinewidth
         ]
{   & & & & & & & & &4&7&7& & & & & & & & &  \\
    & & & & & &5&4&4&8&3&3&4&6&3& & & & & &  \\
    & & & &1&4&5&1&1&1&4&5&1&7&1&3&5& & & &  \\
    & & &4&9&4&9&6&7&5&5&5&8&7&6&6&8&5& & &  \\
    & &3&7&2&9&8&3&5&6&7&3&9&1&8&7&5&8&5& &  \\
    & &1&4&7&8&4&2&9&2&7&1&1&8&2&2&7&6&3& &  \\
    &7&2&1&8&5&5&3&1&1&3&1&3&3&4&2&8&6&1&3&  \\
    &4&2&6&7&2&5&2&4&2&2&5&4&3&2&8&1&7&7&3&  \\
    &4&1&6&5&1&1&1&9&1&4&3&4&4&3&1&9&8&2&7&  \\
   4&3&5&2&3&2&2&3&2&4&2&5&3&5&1&1&3&5&5&3&7 \\
   2&7&1&5&1&1&3&1&5&3&\textcolor{red}{\textbf{3}}
                        &2&4&2&3&7&7&5&4&2&7 \\
   2&5&2&2&6&1&2&4&4&6&3&4&1&2&1&2&6&5&1&8&8 \\
    &4&3&7&5&1&9&3&4&4&5&2&9&4&1&9&5&7&4&8&  \\
    &4&1&6&7&8&3&4&3&4&1&3&1&2&3&2&3&6&2&4&  \\
    &7&3&2&6&1&5&3&9&2&3&2&1&5&7&5&8&9&5&4&  \\
    & &1&6&7&3&4&8&1&1&1&2&1&2&2&8&9&4&1& &  \\
    & &2&5&4&7&8&7&5&6&1&3&5&7&8&7&2&9&3& &  \\
    & & &6&5&6&4&6&7&2&5&2&2&6&3&4&7&4& & &  \\
    & & & &2&3&1&2&3&3&3&2&1&3&2&1&1& & & &  \\
    & & & & & &7&4&4&5&7&3&4&4&7& & & & & &  \\
    & & & & & & & & &3&3&4& & & & & & & & &  \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW - I really need to learn about tikz. (LaTeX is not enough, I guess).
Thanks A LOT!

Comment: @amanzimdwini, you are welcome! Yes, `tikz` is very powerful package with bundle of libraries and excelent (but huge) documentation ...

Answer (score 2):

@Zarko's solution with `tikz` is probably best. But just for comparison, the `nicematrix` package does have the command `\chessboardcolors`, which can create a similar effect by using `corners` and `hvlines`. Note that you must compile 3 times!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{21}{c}}[corners, hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \chessboardcolors{red!15}{blue!15}
\Body
 & & & & & & & & &4&7&7& & & & & & & & &  \\
 & & & & & &5&4&4&8&3&3&4&6&3& & & & & &  \\
 & & & &1&4&5&1&1&1&4&5&1&7&1&3&5& & & &  \\
 & & &4&9&4&9&6&7&5&5&5&8&7&6&6&8&5& & &  \\
 & &3&7&2&9&8&3&5&6&7&3&9&1&8&7&5&8&5& &  \\
 & &1&4&7&8&4&2&9&2&7&1&1&8&2&2&7&6&3& &  \\
 &7&2&1&8&5&5&3&1&1&3&1&3&3&4&2&8&6&1&3&  \\
 &4&2&6&7&2&5&2&4&2&2&5&4&3&2&8&1&7&7&3&  \\
 &4&1&6&5&1&1&1&9&1&4&3&4&4&3&1&9&8&2&7&  \\
4&3&5&2&3&2&2&3&2&4&2&5&3&5&1&1&3&5&5&3&7 \\
2&7&1&5&1&1&3&1&5&3&3&2&4&2&3&7&7&5&4&2&7 \\
2&5&2&2&6&1&2&4&4&6&3&4&1&2&1&2&6&5&1&8&8 \\
 &4&3&7&5&1&9&3&4&4&5&2&9&4&1&9&5&7&4&8&  \\
 &4&1&6&7&8&3&4&3&4&1&3&1&2&3&2&3&6&2&4&  \\
 &7&3&2&6&1&5&3&9&2&3&2&1&5&7&5&8&9&5&4&  \\
 & &1&6&7&3&4&8&1&1&1&2&1&2&2&8&9&4&1& &  \\
 & &2&5&4&7&8&7&5&6&1&3&5&7&8&7&2&9&3& &  \\
 & & &6&5&6&4&6&7&2&5&2&2&6&3&4&7&4& & &  \\
 & & & &2&3&1&2&3&3&3&2&1&3&2&1&1& & & &  \\
 & & & & & &7&4&4&5&7&3&4&4&7& & & & & &  \\
 & & & & & & & & &3&3&4& & & & & & & & &  
\end{NiceTabular}                 
\endgroup

\end{document}
```